# Display different type of content in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to create How it works page where on first view I am displaying youtube video. and on other pages there is information images at place of video. Since UIPageViewController is generally used for displaying similar kind of data (e.g image or text) is there any way to display diff types of content like in this case I want to display video and image at same location.

Comment: i assume content means of only text/audio/video/pic is there anything other than these 4 you want to display ?

Comment: Yes Mr. T I want to show video and pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `UIViewController` to your `UIPageViewController`. So you can add any view to your viewController (`UIWebView` for instance). [Here](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/) you can find some code examples. It's a bit old, but idea is the same.

But nothing is bounding you! You can also use `UICollectionViewController`, with cell sized to screen size. And place in cell any view you need.